# Trigger ng-model change on radio button?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with radio buttons like this:

```
label.has_checkbox(for="workflow_{{workflowSlug}}")
    input(type="radio" ng-model="form.workflow.slug" value="{{workflowSlug}}" name="workflow" id="workflow_{{workflowSlug}}")
```

Now when I operate the app manually and click the radio, the model is set to the value of the radio. The problem is when I trigger the click using jQuery, the radio button gets selected, but the model doesn't get populated with the value.

Comment: Why not try to use `ng-click` of angular rather than the jquery click?

Answer (score 0):

In angular it is supposed to be opposite direction. Data affects the view. So if you want to set the value programmatically you should change the `ng-model` from within angular scope.